# How in phpstorm 2023 to show full path of the loaded project?

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in phpstorm  2023 to show full path of the loaded project ?
Somethimes to need to upload difference versions of the the project
in different phpstorm instances...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A "Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance > Always show full path in windows header" option should help. However, it does not work nicely in the new UI, here is a reference ticket (check relates too): 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UX-2223

Comment: Thank you, but your link is invalid